# No secret management encryption keys were provided while launching elasticsearch entreprise search

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, amazon-opensearch, elastic-enterprise-search

While I am launching the Elasticsearch Enterprise search an error encountered said that the setting secret_management. encryption_keys is not valid. I have checked the search-enterprise.yml file and I gave to this setting a key encryption, but unfortunately the error still encounter.
Please, if someone can help me I will be thankful.

I use as version elasticsearch enterprise search 7.10.2.

./bin/enterprise-search

invalid config file
The setting '#/secret_management/encryption_keys' is not valid
No secret management encryption keys were provided.
Your secrets cannot be stored unencrypted.
You can use the following generated encryption key in your config file to store new encrypted secrets:

secret_management.encryption_keys: [ee2d1265be80f15d24a544adb806aa8d890029091107e594506c8ccb5f58bbff]